# Getting Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 3 Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql

```
Declare @a Decimal;
Declare @b Decimal;

Set @a = 100*(Select price From prices Where prodid = 'a4');
Set @b = 100+(Select cgst from taxes where prodid = 'a4')+(Select sgst from taxes where prodid = 'a4')+(Select cess from taxes where prodid = 'a4')

SELECT
    Round(@a/@b,2) as 'Price per Crtn(excl Taxes)',
    t.cgst+'%' as 'CGST(%)',
    t.cgst*ROUND(@a*0.01/@b,2) as 'CGST Per Crtn',
    t.sgst+'%' as 'SGST(%)',
    t.sgst*ROUND(@a*0.01/@b,2) as 'SGST Per Crtn',
    t.cess+'%' as 'CESS(%)',t.cess*ROUND(@a*0.01/@b,2) as 'CESS Per Crtn',
    r.price as 'Price per Crtn(incl Taxes)',
    '11' as 'Quantity',
    '11'*ROUND(@a/@b,2) as 'Total Price(excl Taxes)', 
    Round(r.price*'11',2) as 'Total Price(incl Taxes)' 
FROM  
    products p 
JOIN 
    prices r ON (r.prodid = p.prodid) 
JOIN
    taxes t ON (t.prodid = r.prodid) 
WHERE
    p.prodid = 'a4'
```

Please help me in getting out of this error as i am trying populate the output of the above query in DataGridview

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a specific problem you've got by following the guidelines how to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what's the data type of the `cgst` column?

Comment: cgst, sgst,cell are float

Comment: @Kande . . . Then `price` would appear to be the problem.

Comment: Hi Frnds, plz find my tables

Comment: @Kande then that's the issue, you are trying to concatenate a float with a string directly: `t.cgst + '%'` ,

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prices] (
    [prodid] NVARCHAR (55) NOT NULL,
    [price]  FLOAT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([prodid] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products] (
    [prodid]          NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [prodname]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [proddescription] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [prodsize]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([prodid] ASC)
);

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[taxes] (
    [prodid] NVARCHAR (55) NOT NULL,
    [igst]   FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [cgst]   FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [sgst]   FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    [cess]   FLOAT (53)    NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([prodid] ASC)
);

Comment: @Lamak can you suggest me how to get output with % symbol next to it

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @kande, use cast or convert to convert float to varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You @Lamak and @Raska
I found answer

```
CAST(t.cgst AS varchar)+'%'
```